schema.prisma file does not migrate to supabase
I have difficulties to migrate a database with prisma file to supabase. here is the information.

Connection string is set correctly in the .env file. all details (host, port, database name, user name, password) are correct
-prisma.schema file and .json file are both in the same root directory.
no network restrictions are set
no error messages appear in the terminal when executing the command: npx prisma migrate dev --name init. but also no created migrations are displayed

-I have restarted the project via supabase

checked the schema file for syntax errors with npx 'prisma validate' (everything is correct)
-checked if any migrations have already been created (not one)
created a shadow database and additionally created the url in the.env file and specified it in the prisma

nothing did work...
